# Package xkbcommon was not found in the pkg-config search path. when building Yocto image

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, pkg-config

On Ubuntu 14.04

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

### Building a **Yocto Poky** image using the **fido** branch

```
inherit core-image
IMAGE_FEATURES += "x11-base x11-sato package-management ssh-server-dropbear"
IMAGE_INSTALL += "chromium \
                  lsb \
                  kernel-modules \
                  alsa-utils \
```

### ... and I am getting this sort of message

I look like it related to the Chromium recipe `/meta-browser/recipes-browser/chromium/chromium_45.0.2454.85.bb` which starts as such

```
include chromium.inc

DESCRIPTION = "Chromium browser"
DEPENDS += "libgnome-keyring"
```

and I get this message

```
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/joel/yocto/build-fido/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/chromium/45.0.2454.85-r0/temp/log.do_configure.28622
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function sysroot_cleansstate
| DEBUG: Python function sysroot_cleansstate finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| Updating projects from gyp files...
| Package xkbcommon was not found in the pkg-config search path.
| Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xkbcommon.pc'
| to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
| No package 'xkbcommon' found
| gyp: Call to 'pkg-config --cflags xkbcommon' returned exit status 1.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

## What I have tried

### Installed the library

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxkbcommon-x11-dev
```

### Search for `xkbcommon.pc`

```
$ apt-file search xkbcommon.pc
libxkbcommon-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/xkbcommon.pc
```

### pkg-config

```
joel@linux-Lenovo-G50-70:~/yocto/build-fido$ pkg-config --cflags xkbcommon
               <=== Return is EMPTY (?)
joel@linux-Lenovo-G50-70:~/yocto/build-fido$ pkg-config --libs xkbcommon
-lxkbcommon    <=== Looks correct
```

### Added `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`

```
 $ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/
 $ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH


 $ env | grep PKG
 PKG_CONFIG_PATH=:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/
```

but I am still getting the same message when running `bitbake`

Any suggestions?

### Find `xkbcommon`

```
$ find /usr/lib/ -name *xkbcommon*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon-x11.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon-x11.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon-x11.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon-x11.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/xkbcommon.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/xkbcommon-x11.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0
```

Comment: You have omitted all the information regarding the error. When does it occur? What is being built? What layers are you using? Machine? etc.

Comment: yes, actually I am trying to figure out how to fix this `xkbcommon` dependency so I figured I could just narrow it down to the error only for clarity. I am building an image for RaspberryPi3 (MACHINE). I will add more detail

Comment: I figured that setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH would just resolve my issue,  wondering if that must be set somewhere in the Yocto config

Comment: Again, when are you getting that packag? Are you building some target package, or some native package? Without knowing this, no-one can help you.

Comment: This is when trying to build Chromium 45 `ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/joel/yocto/build-fido/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-vfp-vfpv4-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/chromium/45.0.2454.85-r0/temp/log.do_configure.28622`.

Comment: Well, your updated question still doesn't state that it fails when building chromium... Which layer comes your chromium recipe from? I've got no idea... Are you sure the your recipe have `libxkbcommon` in it' s`DEPENDS`? There's no reason at all to install `libxkbcommon-x11-dev` on your build machine, as it's a target recipe that wants to find `libxkbcommon`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106603/discussion-between-joel-and-anders).

Comment: And `chromium_45.0.2454.85.bb` doesn't have `libxkbcommon` in the `DEPENDS`. Adding now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it was the chromium recipe that failed to find `libxkbcommon`. As the error occurred when building a recipe for the target system, we need to tell the build system that the chromium recipe has a dependency on `libxkbcommmon`.

This can be done by adding

```
 DEPENDS += "libxkbcommon"
```

to the chromium recipe.

It's worth noting, that `libxkbcommon` quite likely is an optional dependency, and in that case, it should be handled by a suitable `PACKAGECONFIG`. (See [PACKAGECONFIG in ref.manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PACKAGECONFIG)).

> **Note**: I've never built chromium myself, thus I'd prefer to not suggest any suitable `PACKAGECONFIG`.

Comment: I just ran into this too. Seems like a bug in the chromium recipe.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Chromium_45 recipe is taken down since the last time I saw it (don't see it anymore).

Anyway, this is what I did to Chromium_40.
I have disabled Wayland (ozone-wayland in Chromium) so that it will only use x11.

In local.conf, I added
`CHROMIUM_ENABLE_WAYLAND = "0"`

By doing this, I will bypass `CHROMIUM_WAYLAND_DEPENDS = "wayland libxkbcommon"`

```
CHROMIUM_X11_DEPENDS = "xextproto gtk+ libxi libxss"
CHROMIUM_X11_GYP_DEFINES = ""
CHROMIUM_WAYLAND_DEPENDS = "wayland libxkbcommon"
CHROMIUM_WAYLAND_GYP_DEFINES = "use_ash=1 use_aura=1 chromeos=0 use_ozone=1"

python() {
    if d.getVar('CHROMIUM_ENABLE_WAYLAND', True) == '1':
        d.appendVar('DEPENDS', ' %s ' % d.getVar('CHROMIUM_WAYLAND_DEPENDS', True))
        d.appendVar('GYP_DEFINES', ' %s ' % d.getVar('CHROMIUM_WAYLAND_GYP_DEFINES', True))
    else:
        d.appendVar('DEPENDS', ' %s ' % d.getVar('CHROMIUM_X11_DEPENDS', True))
        d.appendVar('GYP_DEFINES', ' %s ' % d.getVar('CHROMIUM_X11_GYP_DEFINES', True))
}
```

P.S.: One more thing I found weird is `use-egl`.
`PACKAGECONFIG[use-egl] = ",,virtual/egl virtual/libgles2"` is overrided with `PACKAGECONFIG[use-egl] = ""` so I have removed `PACKAGECONFIG[use-egl] = ""` from `chromium.inc`

```
PACKAGECONFIG ??= "use-egl"

# this makes sure the dependencies for the EGL mode are present; otherwise, the configure scripts
# automatically and silently fall back to GLX
PACKAGECONFIG[use-egl] = ",,virtual/egl virtual/libgles2"

# Additional PACKAGECONFIG options - listed here to avoid warnings
PACKAGECONFIG[component-build] = ""
PACKAGECONFIG[disable-api-keys-info-bar] = ""
PACKAGECONFIG[ignore-lost-context] = ""
PACKAGECONFIG[impl-side-painting] = ""
PACKAGECONFIG[use-egl] = ""
PACKAGECONFIG[kiosk-mode] = ""
```

Comment: Nice input! Looks like I resolved my current issue but I will certainly give your suggestion a try. Cheers!!